# Bundled Properties with johnson_all_pairs_shortest_paths

Tags: c++, graph, boost

I try to figure out how to use bundle properties with johnson_all_pairs_shortest_paths but did not get the concept. It would to be great to have some examples.

Answer (score 0):

boost::johnson_all_pairs_shortest_paths(topo, distanceMatrix,
boost::weight_map(boost::get(&EdgeProperties::weight, topo)));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).